# How do I avoid line breaks BEFORE OR AFTER an element?

Tags: html, css

I have a definition list. My `<dt>` and `<dd>` are set in CSS as `display: inline-block;`. And I would like to avoid line break before the `<dd>` element and after the `<dt>` element. How can I do it?

My list looks like this, with a line break after term3:

> term1: def1; term2: def2; term3: 
>   def3;

I want it to look like this (the line break should appear before term3:

> term1: def1; term2: def2; 
>  term3: def3;

Answer (score 3):

**Single column (Valid HTML):**

```
<style type="text/css">
    dt, dd { display: inline-block; float: left; }
    dt { clear: left; }
</style>

<dl>
    <dt>term1</dt><dd>def1</dd>
    <dt>term2</dt><dd>def2</dd>
    <dt>term3</dt><dd>def3</dd>
</dl>
```

**No-Wrap `<span>` (Invalid HTML):**

```
<style type="text/css">
    dt, dd { display: inline-block; }
    span { white-space: nowrap; }
</style>

<dl>
    <span><dt>term1</dt><dd>def1</dd></span>
    <span><dt>term2</dt><dd>def2</dd></span>
    <span><dt>term3</dt><dd>def3</dd></span>
</dl>
```

Comment: Using `span` will invalidate the html, just like my solution using `div`.

Comment: @GolezTrol: Yes, I labeled my solution as being Invalid HTML. The major difference between your implementation and mine, is that I don't use `float:left;` on the wrapping elements. :)

Comment: It didn't work the way I wanted. It is always breaking after `<dd>`.
I wanted it to behave like multiples `<span style="white-space: nowrap;">` in one line.

Comment: The first solution is wrong and the second does not seem optimal - I don't want to wrap every use in a <span>.

Comment: BTW, there is no sense in `display: inline-block; float: left;`, cause `float: left;` modifies the computed value of the display value to `display: block;`

Comment: `<span><dt>term1</dt><dd>def1</dd></span>` is best solution. Why it is **Invalid HTML**?

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked by just specifying the `dt` and `dd` on the same line together with `inline` display style, like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    dt, dd { display: inline; }
</style>

<dl>
    <dt>term1</dt><dd>def1</dd>
    <dt>term2</dt><dd>def2</dd>
    <dt>term3</dt><dd>def3</dd>
</dl>
```

instead of what I earlier had:

```
<style type="text/css">
    dt, dd { display: inline; }
</style>

<dl>
    <dt>term1
    <dd>def1
    <dt>term2
    <dd>def2
    <dt>term3
    <dd>def3
</dl>
```

seem to work fine when dynamically resizing the browser window - I never see it break between the `dt` and `dd` only between `dd` and `dt`.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of to do this is to set the width for each of the elements so there is a predictable break point on each line.